# ServiceStack and .NET Core AppSettings complex object

Tags: servicestack

I'm using this from the docs (https://docs.servicestack.net/host-configuration) to load my `appsettings.json` into ServiceStack:

```
AppSettings = new NetCoreAppSettings(Configuration)
```

My `appsettings.json` has this line:

```
"test": [ "a", "b" ]
```

However when I do a `var allSettings = AppSettings.GetAll();` and look for my key `test` it is `null`.

I know .NET core only supports list/dictionary by using .Bind(), and this works:

```
List<string> test = new List<string>();
Configuration.GetSection("test").Bind(test);
```

Since ServiceStack has methods such as `GetList`, `GetDictionary`, and even `Get<T>`, I assume there is something I'm doing wrong since it doesn't work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All of ServiceStack's [AppSettings providers](https://docs.servicestack.net/appsettings) deserializes string scalar values using [JSV Format](https://docs.servicestack.net/jsv-format) so if you wanted to use its `GetList()` or `Get<T>` your **appsettings.json** config would need to look like:

```
"test": "a,b,c"
```

Or

```
"test": "[a,b,c]"
```

Which you can resolve from:

```
var test = AppSettings.GetList("test"); // or
var test = AppSettings.Get<List<string>>("test");
```

Comment: The `AppSettings.Get<List<string>>()` works perfectly. Even with CSV escaping (according to JSV spec), as my real data has commas: "LdapGroups": "[\"cn=something1,ou=Group,o=mycompany.com,cn=XXX\",\"cn=something2,ou=Group,o=mycompany.com,cn=XXX\"]"` but FYI the `GetList` doesn't work as great, as `"[ one,two, three ]"` in appsettings.json gives `"[ one" "two" " three ]"`. My problem is solved anyway.